# How to express a habit in the past (‘would + verb’ in English)

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

In my French coursework I'm trying to form the sentence: “The river would sometimes flood”.

I feel I've taken this far too literally and put:

“Le rivière aurait parfois indoné”

I'm sure that sentence makes no sense, however I can't seem to put it together, I'm fairly terrible at French also.

Comment: Hormis la question, la phrase comporte 3 erreurs de grammaire et d'orthographe: La rivière et non le rivière, inondé et non indoné, et ce verbe demande un COD (inondé quoi ?). plutôt employer déborder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional mood (*aurait*) is only used in hypothetical situations (“Si j'avais su, je ne *serais* pas venu” = “If I had known, I *would* not have come”), or for a future tense with a past base (“Il a dit qu'il *viendrait* le lendemain” = “He said that he *would* come the next day”). It cannot be used in the sense of a habit like *would* can in English.

We just use the *imparfait*.

> La rivière débordait parfois de son lit.

Some other notes on translation:

- *Rivière* is feminine, so *la rivière*.
- *Inonder* is transitive: you can say that a house is flooded (la maison est inondée), but to say that a river is flooding, you need to use another word, such as *déborder* (“de son lit” is more idiomatic but is optional).

Or we might use a different wording — still with the *imparfait*.

> Il y avait parfois des crues.

If it's really important to put some emphasis on the habit, like “would sometimes flood” as opposed to just “sometimes flooded” in English, there are ways, for example:

> Il arrivait parfois à la rivière de déborder.

But don't overuse this; most of the time, “would flood” and “flooded” are both best translated with a straight *imparfait*.

Comment: Still with imparfait: *La rivière pouvait parfois déborder de son lit*

Comment: Et  elle dépassait parfois (de temps en temps) ses rives?

Comment: @Vérace Ça se comprend mais c'est une formulation bizarre.

Comment: Vraiment? "Hier soir le fleuve a depassé ses rives"? Il me semble avoir vu cela (ou similaire) dans les titres suivant de grandes inondations! Mais si tu le dis.

Comment: @Vérace Pour « a dépassé ses rives », [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+d%C3%A9pass%C3%A9+ses+rives%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=ssl) ne trouve qu'un emploi, dans un poème. Pour « [dépassait ses rives](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%C3%A9passait+ses+rives%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=ssl) », ce n'est guère mieux, deux textes (au moins pas poétiques).

Comment: Et "débordé" peut-etre?

Comment: @Vérace Oui, « la rivière a débordé », [c'est courant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22la+rivi%C3%A8re+a+d%C3%A9bord%C3%A9%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: On dit aussi, p.-ê. avec une nuance, _sortir de son lit_ ; _La Loire était sortie de son lit_ ([Ac.9](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/lit/2)), 1690, avec _lit_ dans cet [emploi](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29286n/f193.image) 13e (_Lors retorne li fluns dedanz ses rives et se reclost en son lit._ B. Latini)

Answer (score 0):

L'habitude peut être indiquée en français par:

**être habitué à :**

> La rivière était habituée à déborder.

**avoir l'habitude de :**

> La rivière avait l'habitude de déborder.

**être accoutumé à :**

> La rivière était accoutumée à déborder.

**avoir coutume de :**

> La rivière avait coutume de déborder.

**arriver (forme impersonnelle, qui indique une probabilité limitée):**

> Il arrivait que la rivière déborde.

L'emploi d'adverbe de répétition ou de forme adverbiale: **régulièrement, traditionnellement, fréquemment** (insiste sur la probabilité), **systématiquement** (probabilité très forte, que l'on connaît), **à répétition, usuellement, ordinairement** , **parfois, quelquefois** (probabilité limitée) :

> La rivière débordait régulièrement, ...