# How to express "would (do)" – to talk about what used to happen regularly in the past

Tags: temps-grammatical

> "His brother, moving like quicksilver, **would sneak up** behind him and **knock him out** with a sleeper hold."

I’m trying to translate this English sentence into French:

> Son frère, allant à la vitesse de l'éclair, **se serait glissé** derrière lui et **l'aurait endormi** à l'aide d'une prise de lutte.

Could this specific use of "would {used to}" in English ***ever*** be expressed with the past conditional? An answer from [a similar post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/how-to-express-a-habit-in-the-past-would-verb-in-english) suggests the use of the imparfait instead, but I wonder if there is no exception?

Comment: In a narrative text, the simple past (passé simple) is used for actions.
*Son frère [...] se glissa derrière lui et l'endormit [...]*
However, more context would help.

Comment: @Archa Hi. The sentence is meant for use in casual speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the *imparfait* here, but accompanied by a word or phrase to express how often the event happened. Not using anything would be for something really daily, not occasional like your example. I think you wouldn't use "*would*" there.

So you can say things like :

> **De temps à autres**, son frère, allant à la vitesse de l'éclair, **se glissait** derrière lui et **l'endormissait** à l'aide d'une prise de lutte

You can use : **de temps en temps**, **parfois**, **des fois**, .... They are used for various periods of time.

As Nico Mezet said, you can also use **avoir l'habitude de**, which then changes the tense to infinitive. Notice that "avoir" is in *imparfait*.

To me, it seems like the easiest and most natural way to say it.

---

I also read in the comments that it's meant for casual speech, I didn't correct anything yet because it's not the topic of your question, but that is not *at all* how you would say it casually.

I said "*De temps à autres*" in my example, but the other three are way better fit for casual talk. Other words, like "*se glisser*" and "*lutte*" are not very casual-souding either, but the **most important thing** that you need to remember is that *participe présent* ("allant") is noooooot casual. At all. It's almost never spoken, actually, it's something you read.

It really doesn't have the same level of formality as the "verb+ing" in english. There is quite the different though between "**en allant**" and "**allant**", there are not used in same contexts, but "**en allant**" can be causal as well. Tell me if you want more but again, it's off-topic and my post is already long ;)

Comment: Great explanation. Merci. To be more specific: Although I  mentioned that this sentence was meant for use in casual speech, I intentionally constructed it with a narrative/bookish tone in mind in order to better reflect the original tone perceived in the English sentence.

Comment: Thanks ! Good to know that you knew what you were doing :) By the way, I just noticed that I wrote "it seems to be the easiest way" right after the part about "*avoir l'habitude*", but I didn't mean it about this in particular, I meant the use of periodicity indicators. Both are good.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convey the idea that this would happen regularly, you could use the following construct:

> avait l'habitude de + infinitif

which would translate literally as "had the habit" but can be used to mean "used to"

Your example would become

> Son frère, allant à la vitesse de l'éclair, avait l'habitude de se glisser derrière lui et de l'endormir l'aide d'une prise de lutte.

Comment: How does "avait l'habitude" compare with using the imparfait? "Il se glissait and l'endormait ..." Merci.